# inDesign CC: Adding pages with master spread to document using script

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, generate

I'm new to coding with inDesign and am at a loss for how to achieve this...
Basically I need to generate 50+ brochure range sheets. It's a document that catalogues products using data merging from a .csv file.

What I need to save me time is a script that then inserts enough pages (round up to the nearest 4) and assigns Master-A and Master-B spreads to the covers and penultimate pages.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, though I've done a bit of research and cannot find what it is I need, let alone understand the code. I'm a graphic designer, but I have basic knowledge of HTML. That's about it.

Comment: You are unlikely to find a script that does exactly what you want. You problably want to start [here](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html). The tutorial should show you how to do most of what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AppleScript that will get you started

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2019"
    tell document 1
        repeat until (count of pages) is 8
            make pages
        end repeat
        set applied master of pages to (item 1 of (master spreads whose name prefix is "A"))
        set applied master of page 1 to (item 1 of (master spreads whose name prefix is "B"))
        set applied master of page -1 to (item 1 of (master spreads whose name prefix is "B"))
    end tell
end tell
```